# Whats wrong with my User Input Code?

Tags: java

Everytime I use this code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{

public static void main (String args []){
System.out.println("What is your name?");
Scanner name = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Hello," + name);
}
}
```

It just gives me random letters like:

Hello,java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false]

Please someone help.

Answer (score 2):

Because what you are doing is actually just printing out the Scanner's `toString` method since in your code, the object name is actually an instance of Scanner, which is NOT a string.

You need to call the method to actually read the user input.

What you need to do is do something like this

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{

public static void main (String args []){
System.out.println("What is your name?");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
String name = scanner.next();
System.out.println("Hello," + name);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner name = new Scanner (System.in);
```

Using this you have created an scan reference. Use this to read the name like

```
String str = name.next();
```

Read about [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing reference of Scanner.
If you want to input an integer, Write

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
int n = in.nextInt();
```

If you want to input a string, write

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String n = in.next();
```